What is that movie with Malcolm McDowell that is about a demonic apocalypse?
I'm almost certain that the movie had Malcolm McDowell in it. But if he was in it, I cannot find it under his movies.
The movie was about a demon or the devil or the devil's son taking over the world. There was a group of individuals that was helping the demon (just to generalize, so I don't have to specify every time that it may not have been a demon). It was a group of seemingly wealthy men. The demon was going after an artifact of some sort (an ancient book or something such as that) to make itself stronger.
Eventually, the demon uses what I think was green flames or something of the sort to kill the group of men that was helping it. I think the demon was going after someone, as well; it might have been because they had the artifact. It has been a long time since I've seen it, so the details might not be exactly correct, but I know they're close. The movie is at least five years old.
Does anyone know what movie this is?

Can you tell us an approximate year? (The only one with a demonic William Fichtner that springs to mind is Drive Angry, and that's only 4 years old.)

I don't know the year, but it has to be at least 5 years old. It is not Drive Angry. As I said, I could not find it anywhere under movies in which William Fichtner played, but I'm most certain he was in it. If William Fichtner wasn't in it (that's a big if), it must have been someone that looked very much like him.

Sure it wasn't William Sadler?

@NapoleonWilson I don't believe I've seen him before, so he could have been in the movie. If he was, though, it doesn't say he was. In the case of instead of William Fichtner, I'm sure it was not William Sadler.

Is it possible you've mistaken William Fichtner with Gabriel Byrne?

@Dannie Well, they look nothing alike to me and the movie isn't found under his movies either, so I would say no - I did not confuse William Fichtner with Gabriel Byrne.

Should be a simple matter of going through Fichtner's work then.

@Dannie It should, but it isn't. I cannot find it under his work. I could be remembering his presence in the movie completely wrong, but I remember it so vividly.

I was wrong. It was Malcolm McDowell, not William Fichtner. I still cannot find the movie in his titles, though. Why is this movie so hard to find? I've looked under horror movies, movies about an apocalypse, movies about demons or the devil, (mistakenly) William Fichtner's movies, and finally Malcolm McDowell's movies, and I still cannot find it!

This one stars Michael York, but I'll give it a try.
Megiddo: The Omega Code 2 (2001)
From Wikipedia:

Stone and his officers are swallowed in a huge fireball as tank shells
  rain in. David barely manages to break free and jump away before the
  headquarters explodes behind him. But he is stunned as Stone walks
  out of the ashes and morphs into a massive demon with ram's horns and
  huge leathery wings. After seriously wounding David he summons up
  his dark brethren as reinforcements and revives his dead army. In a
  full display of his supernatural powers, he even darkens the sun,
  plunging the whole battlefield into darkness.

